# Controller repeatedly calling itself in Spring-MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was trying to just output my request with just a direct write to the response object. This works great with servlets but with Spring-MVC I ended up creating an infinite loop for some reason I don't understand. Basically the controller just gets called repeatedly. I don't even know how that is possible.

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
        throws ServletException, IOException
{
    System.out.println("I will get called infinitely");
    response.getWriter().print( "Hello World!");
    response.getWriter().close();
    return new ModelAndView();

}
```

So the question is, does anyone know why it would cause an infinite amount of re-requests to this page? It seems to only occur when I am creating a ModelAndView() with nothing in it. But in this case I don't want anything in it, just a blank page. So secondly then is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: This depends on what your view technology is and how your view resolvers are set up.  is it JSP?  Have you manually configured any view resolvers in your dispatcher servlet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to return `null`, instead of `ModelAndView`, and call `flush()` instead of `close()`. Like this,

```
public ModelAndView handleRequest( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("I will get called infinitely");
    response.getWriter().print( "Hello World!");
    response.getWriter().flush();
    return null;    
}
```

NOTE: I am not sure, whether `close()` will commit the `response` or not, but `flush()` will.

Answer (score 1):

Probably an empty viewName of the ModelAndView class will cause that the view from the current request will be used.

You can use `void` or `@ResponseBody String` as return type.